# React: is it bad practice to render HTML conditionally based on state?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
const Foo = () => {
    const [a, setA] = useState(false);

    const bar = a ? <div 
        className="box-50px-x-50px"
        style={{
            backgroundColor: a ? 'red' : 'green',
        }}
    />;

    return <>{bar}</>
}
```

Doing this kind of thing works exactly as I'd expect. Does this kind of thing make sense in React?

Answer (score 0):

As the `react` docs says

> [Inline If-Else with Conditional Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator) :
> Conditionally rendering elements inline is to use the JavaScript conditional operator **condition ? true : false.**
> It can also be used for larger expressions although it is less obvious what’s going on:

To maintain consistent and readable style use [Inline If with Logical && Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

Comment: I'm not asking about whether or not the use of conditional operator is OK. I'm asking about whether or not this will work as I expect every time

Comment: When you want to return nothing or an element inside JSX. It's also called short-circuit evaluation which makes it even more concise than a ternary operator.